# Убрать пунктирную обводку, возникающую после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, tkinter

При нажатии на кнопку в моей программе кнопка приобретает пунктирную обводку, я не знаю как ее убрать.

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter

from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import messagebox

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("512x512")
root.title("Вход")

def faq():
    messagebox.showinfo("text 1", "text 2")

btn = ttk.Button(text = "Пустая кнопка")
btn.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
btn2 = ttk.Button(text = "?",
    width = 3,
    command = faq)
btn2.grid(column = 2, row = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пунктиром выделяется объект, содержащий [фокус](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)). Можно после нажатия принудительно переводить фокус на все окно:

```
def faq():
    messagebox.showinfo("text 1", "text 2")
    root.focus()
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло :)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению в tkinter обводка будет всегда. Единственное решение - попробовать сменить тему использовав модуль ttkthemes, но и он врядли поможет.