# Убрать чёрную обводку RadioButton tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobutton

Всем здравствуйте. Хотел бы спросить, есть ли способ в tkinter RadioButton убрать чёрную обводку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чем ответ не усроил?

Comment: @ganz автор вопроса мог еще не увидеть ответ, а во-вторых я подозреваю, что черная обводка - это не border, а обозначение, что виджет в фокусе, и чтобы убрать эту обводку, нужно убрать фокус, например через `root.focus()` после выбора пункта, примерно как в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1081510/1365

Comment: @insolor не думаю... полагаю автору нужен был лишь ответ... но встроил ваше предложение в правильный ответ

Comment: @ganz "полагаю автору нужен был лишь ответ." - полагаю, автору нужен ответ, который решает его проблему, а не просто рандомный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы убрать чёрную обводку вокруг изображения в компоненте `RadioButton` в tkinter, вы можете использовать опцию `borderwidth` со значением `0` при создании экземпляра `RadioButton`. Например:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

rb = Radiobutton(root, image=image, borderwidth=0)
rb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Это установит ширину обводки радио-кнопки равной `0`, что приведёт к тому, что обводка не будет видна.

Comment: Вы попробовали свой ответ? У меня на windows 10 не работает.

Comment: не работает ваш способ